# Is there a term for an acronym "parody" / "backformation" / "re-purposing"?

Tags: single-word-requests, ambiguity, acronyms, initialisms

I've engaged the task of trying to legitimize the presence of a listing of DRM standing for "Digital Restrictions Management" on Wikipedia's [disambiguation page for the acronym DRM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DRM).

*(This is a case where the original term stood for "Digital Rights Management", which is considered by the activist cause as whitewashing the true implications; as it may only limit/restrict and never grant any rights on the digital media to the users if the limitations were not present.  It is advocated as a replacement meaning for the acronym by the [Defective by Design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defective_by_Design) movement.)*

I'm not sure what to call an acronym with this character.  The terms that came to mind were "parody", "backformation", or "re-purposing".  Is there a more general term for taking an acronym that was marketed and understood as meaning one thing and promoting an alternate meaning?

Comment: *(...and if people with any Wiki cred could have my back on this deserving mention on the DRM disambiguation page--with a link to the Defective by Design Movement--that would be cool too.)*

Comment: DRM is not an acronym. An acronym is letters that form a pronounceable word like PETA or SCUBA.

Comment: @DarrickHerwehe The tag description for [tag:acronym] here says *"Acronyms are words which were created by taking the first letter (or several letters) of each word of a phrase."*  That's the definition I know of...

Comment: DRM is a kind of *acronym* called an *[initialism](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/initialism)*.

Comment: @Dispensador I've added [tag:initialisms] as it exists here.  But I suppose the question is if that is a subclass of acronym or not?  Are all initialisms acronyms?

Comment: I'm sure purists would say they are separate things entirely, because initialisms are pronounced by their letters: RIA, FSF. Acronyms are pronounced like they are spelled: SCUBA, RADAR.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The term *backronym* comes to mind: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backronym

Comment: That's a good/funny word...though it doesn't quite convey the nuance I'm looking for.  I mention the wiki page because I was wondering if something existed better than *"re-purposing of the acronym"* (which was the best I came up with)

Comment: Well, going down the wikipedia rabbit hole you've also got [retronym](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Retronym), [satiric misspelling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satiric_misspelling) (maybe you have satiric acronyming?), and [sensational spelling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sensational_spelling) (maybe you have sensational acronyming?). Who is trying to repurpose the acronym? What do they call the repurposing?

Answer (score 4):

It sounds to me like you are [*reappropriating*](http://gog.is/define+reappropriate) the term for a new use.

Comment: Not acronym-specific, but good to add to the consideration.

Comment: *[Co-opt](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/co-opt#Verb)*, in sense “To commandeer, appropriate or take over” is somewhat parallel to *reappropriate*, minus the overtones of “...a group reclaims — re-appropriates — terms or artifacts that were previously used in a way disparaging of that group”.